# SQL inner join not retrieving records

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am attempting to join 2 tables.

Table 1 (resource_log) is a data feed comprising of various columns, date, time, contact number etc. Every time a transaction occurs and new row is inserted into the table.

Table 2 (directory) is a directory which provides a name, team, contact number etc.

Contents in Table 2 are updated every so often, with the previous records retained, and more recent records having a recent record date (rdate).

What I want to do – is display records between 2 times and join the most recent directory information from table 2.

I have written this which pulls back both tables but no results.

I'll use a concrete, but hypothetical, example.

```
SELECT      top 20 * 
FROM        resource_log r
INNER JOIN          directory
ON          substring(rl.issi,4,4) = 
                    (
                     SELECT     distinct top 1 d.rdate                           
                     FROM       directory d             
                     WHERE      substring(d.id,2,4) = substring(r.id,4,4)           
                     ORDER BY   d.rdate desc
                      )
WHERE       r.date_and_time between '2016-09-13 11:00:00' and '2016-09-13 11:10:00' and r.id = '123456'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you verified that `substring(rl.issi,4,4)` is correct. Also verify `substring(d.id,2,4)`

Comment: What I generally do on this issue is change the inner join to a full outer join.  Then compare the fields I am trying to inner join on and see where they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `cross apply` or `outer apply`:

```
SELECT top 20 * 
FROM resource_log r OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 d.rdate                           
      FROM directory d             
      WHERE substring(d.id, 2, 4) = substring(r.id, 4, 4)           
      ORDER BY d.rdate desc
     ) d
WHERE r.date_and_time between '2016-09-13 11:00:00' and '2016-09-13 11:10:00' and
      r.id = '123456';
```

This will return `resource_log` records with no matching directory.  If you don't want them, then use `CROSS APPLY`.

Also, there is no need for `distinct` in the subquery, because you are only selecting one value.